# Close erroneous mongoose connection

Tags: node.js, error-handling, mongoose

When mongoose fails to connect to the DB, how do I properly end the script?

The following keeps running:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db', function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }
});
```

I also tried `mongoose.disconnect()` with the same result.

The easiest way is obviously `throw err;` but this seems a brutal hammer solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `connect` function failed (i.e. `err != null`) that means the connection state is not open, therefore, you can't close or disconnect it.

To prove it to yourself, you can check the `mongoose.connection.readyState` (here are the [available values](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-readyState)).

May I suggest using `mongoose.connection.on('error', cb);` to better handle connection errors.

Comment: But then how do I handle the error? the script keeps on running as long as I do not throw the error manually. There is nothing mor in there than the above lines.

Comment: You handle the error inside the callback function (that's what cb stands for)

Comment: It seems like a problem with my local installation, checked it on a different setup and there the code simply quits. Have to dive into it... Is there a way to see which processes keep a script running?